# Multiple info windows for each geojson on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

So far I only have 3 geojson sources. maybe in the future there will be more than 3 sources that I will use. on my code, it can only display one 'info windows'. what I want to ask is how do I display info windows for each geojson source?

```
var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: {lat: -2.9365327, lng: 104.4950964}
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var foo1 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
    foo1.loadGeoJson('https://rawgit.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json');

    var foo2 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
    foo2.loadGeoJson('https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.geojson');

    var foo3 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
    foo3.loadGeoJson('https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_geography_regions_points.geojson');

    foo1.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'green',
      strokeColor: 'green',
      strokeWeight: 1
    });

    foo2.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'blue',
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      strokeWeight: 1
    });


    foo3.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'green',
      strokeColor: 'red',
      strokeWeight: 1
    });

    $('#foo1').click(function(){
      foo1.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
    });

    $('#foo2').click(function(){
      foo2.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
    });
    $('#foo3').click(function(){
      foo3.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
    });

    $('#foo1,#foo2,#foo3').removeAttr('disabled');

    $('#all').click(function(){
      foo1.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
      foo2.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
      foo3.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#all').click(function() {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
      });
    })

    var ced = google.maps.event.addListener(foo1, 'click', function(event) {
      var aab=event.feature.l.name;
      infowindow.setContent('<div class="col-md-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><table class="table table-striped"><tr><th>ID</th><td>'+aab+'</td></tr><tr><th>Latitude</th><td>'+ event.latLng.lat()+'</td></tr><tr><th>Longitude</th><td>'+ event.latLng.lng()+'</td></tr></table></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-md-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'+aab+'">Detail</button></div></div></div>');
      console.log(event.feature.l)
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
      infowindow.open(map);
    });

    foo1.data.addListener('mouseover', function (event) {
      foo1.data.revertStyle();
      foo1.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWeight: 8,
        visibility: 'off'

      });   
    });

    foo1.data.addListener('mouseout', function (event) {
      foo1.data.revertStyle();
    });
  }
```

as you can see, I have three different sources.
[image: image1]

and when clicked only one source successfully displays windows info. at this image only works for 'var foo1'
[image: image2]

can someone help me?

Comment: Create one InfoWindow object for each GeoJSON.

Comment: already do it but stil not working

Comment: The above code doesn't show that you are already doing that. And just saying "it doesn't work" won't help anyone to understand what the issue is.

Comment: I mean, I've tried it but it didn't work, so I returned the code to the origin. so, I didn't put it in my above code

Comment: Right. Check my answer. But as a general advice: when you are trying to achieve something and it doesn't work, it's better to show what you have tried and how and explain what doesn't work. Otherwise it might sound like you didn't even try anything... ;)

Comment: if I found the answer I will immediately change my question to tell the code that is successful. see my last question, no one answer and i found it. so that doesn't mean that I'm not trying to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not including your entire code but you should be able to do something like that:

```
var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

And then use them separately in your event listeners:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(foo1, 'click', function(event) {

  infowindow1.setContent('xxx');
  infowindow1.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow1.open(map);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(foo2, 'click', function(event) {

  infowindow2.setContent('xxx');
  infowindow2.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow2.open(map);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(foo3, 'click', function(event) {

  infowindow3.setContent('xxx');
  infowindow3.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow3.open(map);
});
```

**Edit:** Your question now being different than the original, here is how you can dynamically load your various sources, set your styles, events, etc. so you can add as many layers and sources as you want. The code is **an example** and shows the base idea. Use it and adapt it to cover all your events and other needs.

Note the use of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on the event listener as you are using this in a loop and use the same approach for any other event you want to attach.

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 6.17);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var sources = [
    {
      url: 'https://rawgit.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json',
      fillColor: 'yellow',
      strokeColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      url: 'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.geojson',
      fillColor: 'blue',
      strokeColor: 'green'
    },
    {
      url: 'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_geography_regions_points.geojson',
      fillColor: 'pink',
      strokeColor: 'white'
    }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {

    let d = new google.maps.Data({
      map: map
    });

    d.loadGeoJson(sources[i].url);

    d.setStyle({
      fillColor: sources[i].fillColor,
      strokeColor: sources[i].strokeColor,
      strokeWeight: 1
    });

    let iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(d, 'click', (function(d, i) {

      return function(event) {

        iw.setContent('Content for IW of source ' + i);
        iw.setPosition(event.latLng);
        iw.open(map);
      }

    })(d, i));
  }
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: im already do like this and this is works fine, but the problem is at this moment i only have 3 source, and if i have 100 source ++ , Do I have to type it one by one?

Comment: No, but then the issue is the same with the rest of your code as well... not only InfoWindows. How are you going to load the JSON files? To set the styles? The event listeners, etc.? You'd need a dynamic way of doing all what you do in your code, except for creating the map.

Comment: I'm not very good at stringing words into asking, so I just write what I think for a moment.